# Joining 2 dataframes based on one columns

Tags: r

I searched for an answer for some hours but I just couldn't find one. I have to immensely big data sets and I'm trying to combine them to one my problem is with all the answers I get an even bigger data set.

The first dataset contains 120000 rows the second 370000. They both have the same column ID, but the larger one just has a certain amount of IDs from the smaller one.
The end product should be like in this example

```
id name country
1  John USA
2  Mary Portugal
3  Jeff Spain
4  Fred USA
```

Second dataset:

```
id time 
1  12:00
2  11:12
2  06:34
2  07:21
4  15:34
4  18:45
```

final data frame:

```
id name country  time
1  John USA      12:00
2  Mary Portugal 11:12
2  Mary Portugal 06:34
2  Mary Portugal 07:21
4  Fred USA      15:34
4  Fred USA      18:45
```

What also would be nice is to know why I got more rows then beforehand with merge(all = FALSE)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the first table has unique ids, then you can

```
merge(second, first, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
```

If both tables have non-unique ids, you will automatically get replications.

Comment: can you just briefly explain to me what you mean with unique and non-unique ids

Comment: Unique means each value of the key/id occurs exactly once  in the table.